# $("#input").keyup not working where as $(document).keyup does

Tags: jquery

In Chrome 30.0.1599.101 and IE 11 the input selector does not function where as it is fine in Firefox 25.0.1

Broken in Chrome/IE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#input").keyup(function (e) {
        var dataString = $(this).val();
        console.log(dataString);
    });
});
```

Working in Chrome/IE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        var dataString = $("#input").val();
        console.log(dataString);
    });
});
```

Yet this fiddle works in all browsers...
http://jsfiddle.net/f82Dz/1/

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you have more than one #input

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Is the `#input` added after the page is loaded and DOM is created (i.e. with AJAX or similar)?  If so you need to delegate the event and that's why it's not working.

Comment: `#input` should be `input`, if the elements don't exist on creation please use `$('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) { });`

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/f82Dz/2/

Comment: @abc123 If that were the problem, it wouldn't work in Firefox, either.

Comment: and it also assumes he wants the listener on all inputs

Comment: @karthikr What's yout point? It works in his fiddle, too.

Comment: @Barmar he gave his input an ID of `input` that's just bad naming and you know it.

Comment: unless there are multiple inputs with same id or input is generated dynamically, this should work. can you post your actual code here? complete html and js

Comment: @abc123 I agree that it's a bad ID, but changing the selector isn't the right solution, changing the ID might be.

Comment: @abc123 yes that is a bad name and isn't used in my real code. Anyway .on worked instead so thanks to you as well as Ennui

Comment: You might want to check, if there is any code that stops the propagation of `keyup`-events up to the `document`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this fix it?  If the `input` is added dynamically after the page is first loaded you need to delegate the event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('keyup', '#input', function (e) {
        var dataString = $("#input").val();
        console.log(dataString);
    });
});
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f82Dz/3/)**

Event handlers are only bound to DOM elements that exist at the time you bind the event - in this case on `$(document).ready()`.  If your `input` is not present at that time and is added later with AJAX or another method you need to use event delegation like in this example.

If that does not work, you need to provide more context / information.

Comment: Is it added dynamically some other way? Perhaps by some JS that runs later in the page after you bind the event?  Otherwise it doesn't make sense why your original code didn't work!  Thanks for marking the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Honestly no idea. The JS is in `head` and the `form` `echo`'d in PHP. Nothing dynamic about it.